# Eclipse android application min3d error

Tags: android, opengl-es, java-3d

I had checked out the min3d from google code and tried to import that into the eclipse.

for that I went to File -> New -> other -> Android and selected Open existing Android application from source

and selected `min3d-read-only\sampleProjects\min3dSampleProject1`
and clicked next

Now I got the following error `" Build path contains duplicate entry :'src' for project "SplashActivity"`

Reason `" Build path contains duplicate entry :'src' for project "SplashActivity"`

Please give me a little hand to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

The file you have downloaded is not meant for you to run as an application, it is just a source code for your reference.

if you want to see the application, you can go to Google Play to download the application,

and you can include the library provided in the src folder into your application project.